# Dirty but empty date field is invalid in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an input date field which I want to validated through Angular.

```
<input ng-model="date" type="date" class="form-control" name="date">
```

When user modifies the field and then removes all changes, the input stays in invalid state, since the input is not required, shouldn't this be valid once all content is removed from the input.

Comment: you want to validate through Angular, tell me what kind of validation is it please

Answer (score 0):

angular simplifies things, a blank input hooked up to ngModal returns a value of undefined while native javascript holds a value of '' (empty string). 
Example HTML:

```
<h1>Angular '' = "undefined";</h1>
<main ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demoCtrl">  
  <input ng-model="someModel" ng-blur="showVal(someModel)" type="text"/>
</main>
<h1>Native JS</h1>
<input type="text" onblur="javascript:alert(this.value)"/>
<h1>Blur each element to see the value returned from each in an alert</h1>
```

Example JS:

```
 (function(angular) {
   "use strict";
   var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
   demo.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {

     $scope.showVal = function(valu) {
       return alert(valu);
     };

   });
 })(window.angular);
```

This code is demonstrated here: http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/GJOVVP

It will alert the value of an empty text node through AngularJS and then again with inline JS for simplicity sake. This should show you what I mean.